# How can I send the Name of the Item instead of PK in Django-Rest-Framework using POSTMAN?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, postman

So I am creating a E-Commerce API using the Django Rest Framework and I have been trying to send the name of the Item instead of the PK of the Item to create an order.

These are the models I am using:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_tag = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.png")
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_created"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class PlacedOrder(models.Model):
    ordered_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    total_price = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ordered_by}"
```

This is my serializer that I am working with to create an order:

```
class PlacedOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ordered_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="ordered_by.email")

    class Meta:
        model = PlacedOrder
        fields = (
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "ordered_by",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone",
            "address",
            "zipcode",
            "items",
            "total_price",
        )
```

Here is the view I am using to create an order:

```
class CreateOrder(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    queryset = PlacedOrder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlacedOrderSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(ordered_by=self.request.user)
```

This is my input in POSTMAN:

```
{
    "first_name": "yes",
    "last_name": "no",
    "phone": "0100000000",
    "address": "whatever address",
    "zipcode": "254",
    "items": [
            1,
            1,
            2
        ],

    "total_price": "69"
}
```

and this is the output:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "created_at": "2022-10-26T20:56:08.789574Z",
    "ordered_by": "bal@bal.com",
    "first_name": "yes",
    "last_name": "no",
    "phone": "0100000000",
    "address": "whatever address",
    "zipcode": "254",
    "items": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "total_price": 69
}
```

I basically want it to take the name and quantity of the items instead of the PK of the product in the input.

I have tried using RelatedField but that makes it so that "items" just goes null to the backend without taking any products and makes a blank order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```py
class PlacedOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # HERE
    ordered_by = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PlacedOrder
        fields = (
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "ordered_by",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone",
            "address",
            "zipcode",
            "items",
            "total_price",
        )
```

But make sure to add `self.name` to the models `__str__`.

Comment: Should I add the __str__ in the PlacedOrder model?

Comment: This is just to return the name you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to use a SlugRelatedField [DRF-doc] here, like:
class PlacedOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ordered_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="ordered_by.email")
    items = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        slug_field='name',
        queryset=Product.objects
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PlacedOrder
        fields = (
            # ...
        )
This will thus make the serializer interpret the name fields, and query the Product objects with that name, and add these to the many-to-many relation.
Note that this will result in a query for each item, so if the list of items can be long, you might want to consider a different strategy, like serializing a list of product PKs, and then in the view construct a mapping name -> product, and use that to construct the many-to-many relation.

Note: It is normally better to use a slug field (a short identifier), than a name field for these kinds of relations. Slugs are meant to be database friendly (only contain ascii characters, no spaces, etc), and furthermore slugs normally do not change, whilst a name can. So if you later rename a Product, then the order will no longer point to the correct product.
```